# Textarea overlaid on div - Alignment issues on iOS 8

Tags: html, css, ios8

On iOS 8, I'm overlaying a div with a textarea, with the same text and resetting every margin/padding values, but there's still an offset of 3px that I can't get rid of. It works great on Chrome and Safari desktop.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfvz0ved/

```
textarea, div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    font-family: Courrier;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: transparent;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    resize: none;
    width: 100%;
    color: black;
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

Any idea what property could cause this issue? I don't want to resort to a browser detection + special class if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite a bit of research, it turns out iOS is adding a 3px padding and it can't (apparently) be removed. So the best way to go about it is to compensate for it. I've added a `left: 3px` on the div when iOS is detected. It's not ideal (I'd have loved to avoid that and have a CSS only solution), but it works.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you apply a universal CSS reset?

If that fixes the problem, then one of the containing elements might need to be reset.

Comment: Nothing happens as far as I can see. I tried both reset.css and normalize.css.

Comment: Try removing "width: 100%" and/or try adding "overflow: hidden".